# Curve creating in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

In need to create the curves, I marked in blue in blender and repeat the process for at least 6 times more.

Is there any fast way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any automatic way to do it easily, what you can do is:

- Use the Mirror modifier to repeat the shape symmetrically

[image]

- Enable the *Proportional Editing* option / *Connecte*d and *Sphere* mode.

[image]

- Move one central vertex, the others will follow. I've left the topology as it is (with ngons) but it might need some corrections depending on what's your final purpose.

[image]

- Use several *Array* modifiers to repeat the pattern.

[image]